# Was the DataGridView UI designed to enter data directly into the cells or is it better to add/update an entire row at once?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to figure out if the DataGridView UI was designed to allow the end-user to literally enter a row of data cell-by-cell. Some of the functionality I have seen in my attempt to use the DataGridView as the first and last UI for entering a row of data lead me to believe that it might be easier, like 10x easier, to just put up a separate "Add Record" dialog and when the user is done adding what constitutes a row of data then add that entire row.

In the UserAddedRow event handler you would think that one of the arguments to the handler would be the new row but it's not. It's a new one that the user isn't even entered data in. It's just odd things like this that make me wonder.

Comment: `UserAddedRow`'s `e.Row` returns the index of the Row just added. The event is raised as soon as a non-automatic  value is added to the `NewRow` object (a DataTable's PK, for example, is presented automatically, but it doesn't raise the event, you can just go back to an existing cell and the value is removed). You have a lot of other events you can rely upon for different tasks.

Comment: The `UserAddedRow` event will ONLY fire if the user “clicks” into a cell and enters a character into that cell that is in the last empty row. The last empty row is the grids “new row.” This would mean that the grids `AllowUserToAddRows` property is `true`. If its `false` the event will NEVER fire. As Jimi points out, you can get the “index” of the new row or the row the user entered data into from this event. In the event… `e.Row.Index` will return the row index of the “NEW ROW” NOT the row the user is currently in.

Comment: Since you KNOW for sure that the user clicked into a cell, typed a character into that cell and that cell was the current “New Row”… then the `UserAddedRow` event will fire… however, before the event is fired… the grid “ADDS” a new row. Therefore, the row the user entered data into would be `e.Row.Index - 1`.

Comment: Lastly, as you mentioned… _”that it might be easier, like 10x easier, to just put up a separate "Add Record" dialog”_ … This I can agree with depending on what is needed. Example, if the data the user inputs needs some special validation or needs to enter “REQUIRED” fields… then IMHO this will not only be easier in a pop-up form but will also be more user friendly. You can easily “validate” and check required fields directly in the grid as the user enters data; however, I am betting it will involve more work than a simple pop-up would.